# PHP is removing a newline typed after an echo statement

Tags: php

Consider test.php

```
OK
here
<?php echo "now"; ?>
what
```

if you were to run this file, you could expect it to output following:

```
OK
here
now
what
```

But it returns

```
OK
here
nowwhat
```

What is causing this? Can it be prevented?

P.S.

If you add any character after the line where php code is, even a space, then the newline is retiained.

```
OK
here
<?php echo "now"; ?>[space]
what
```

Comment: You need to explicitly echo the newline. PHP won't do it unless you tell it to.

Comment: @aynber There already is a newline in the file. it seems php is removing it. Because if I simply add a space after the php line, then the newline works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. **The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.**

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

So the "eating" of a newline is expected behavior. The work around as you found is to put a space, or use the above answer and add a \n.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the portion in docs. I guess there is no way to change that behavior in ini.

Answer (score -1):

Please add a break tag inside echo

```
OK
here
<?php echo "now <br>"; ?>
what
```

And your output will be like this:

```
OK
here
now
what
```

Comment: This question isn't about how to create new line. It's about why php removing `\n` after `?>`. by the way if you want to create new line in this example you need to create it with `\n` not `<br>`